# How to redirect from example.com/path/file to http://example.com/path/file with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

So wheter there is path or not i want to redirect example.com/* to http://example.com/*

*I've heard that having static URL is good for SEO, for example if visitors navigate to www.example.com/path or just example.com/path i'll be redirecting them to http://example.com/path*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```